# AWS Glue : How to make sure glue crawler always picks up the latest file from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I have an ETL pipeline which outputs a .csv files into S3 every 15 minutes. How can I configure a glue crawler such that it picks up only the latest file instead of using all the files.

Answer (score 0):

Using [incremental crawls:](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/incremental-crawls.html)

> For an Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) data source, incremental crawls only crawl folders that were added since the last crawler run. Without this option, the crawler crawls the entire dataset.
> ... To perform an incremental crawl, you can set the Crawl new folders only option in the AWS Glue console or set the RecrawlPolicy property in the CreateCrawler request in the API.

Comment: Thanks @newbie, I tried that but it appends the data to the existing table. I want it to drop and pick only the latest file.

Comment: So if I understood you correctly, you want the crawler to drop the table and create a new one containing only the newly added data? If so, update your question because that's not what you are asking for.

Comment: @newbie In my s3 location we have compaction limit to 5 which is default that means I will be having new parquet file created after every 5 records added and once the new parquet file is created it will have new data as well as old data from older parquet file....now when I try to query the data from athena it queries both new and older parquet file thats why i am getting duplicate data....Is there any way that I can read only latest parquet file from athena or crawler..?